# How do I manage multiple file management for users?

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload

I want to have a very small web application (using PHP) that allows the user to add a text file. edit it and then save it.

**my question is - if I have 100 users - and they all upload the file "myFile.txt" - how do I manage that each file will be saved in a different place - so they won't rewrite one another?**

Do I need to attach to it a random number like:
myFile_randomness010101010.txt  - so I will know which file belongs to who?
and then what? I just take this number out when they want to download what they have changed? and how do I know which files goes to who?

I think the answer has something to do with Cookies - but I don't know how exactly..

How does it work? where do I start?
thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward really. Append a time and possible some unique id (possibly simple `uniqid()`). If you don't want the time to be readable, consider hashing it.

Now the main thing you are worried about is getting the file back, right? It would be best to just store both the original name and the tempered one in a database. That means you can show the original name on the frontend, but work with the unique one.

Other solutions are not so much fail proof. You can append the user's SID for example, but that means the user would not get the file in another session (and possibly other users might edit theirs to get it themselves).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right about cookies. You can implement this using a [Session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). PHP session use Cookies.

A simple approach:

```
//uploadbegin.php or login.php etc
session_start();

//validate user logon and
$_SESSION['USERNAME'] = <user name>
```

The following handles the file upload part.

```
//fileupload.php

session_start(); //start the session..

$user = $_SESSION['USERNAME'];

$content = //get the contents of the file received by HTTP Post to a file or a database.

$rand = //some random number

$fileName = "$user/file$rand";

//this file may be inside a directory named after the user or something like that.
file_put_contents($fileName, $content);

//add this filename and path to the database along with the $user.
```

Now for obtaining the file contents, check the `$_SESSION` variable(after the user logs on or something like that), get the file path, spit out the content onto some HTML editable control.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

What I have always done for this is to store the file in a folder that is named the id of the file in a database. That way the original file name is preserved, and the folder names will be relatively short, and you don't technically need to store anything but the id in the database as the only file in the folder is the one you'll be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies would work; create a random hash then use PHP's `set_cookie()` to keep that hash on their computer for as long as you would like, then call the cookie if it exists when the visitor comes to the page.

```
$fileName=($_COOKIE['your_cookie_name']) ? $_COOKIE['your_cookie_name'].'.txt' : 'myFile.txt';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new directory for each user - name it based on something unique in the their database record such as user id.

When you go to move the file to its new location you move it to /files/$userid/ for example.

Then to access the files you would do the same thing img src="files/$userid/filename" for example.

No crossover, no chance of overwriting from someone else, other users cannot access files (unless they are given access or know the userid)